# Why is my task that wraps a call to CloudBlockBlob.BeginDownloadToStream blocking forever when run in ASP.NET?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, task-parallel-library, azure-blob-storage

I have an issue where a Task created with `Task.Factory.FromAsync` is never completing. Its status remains on `System.Threading.Tasks.TaskStatus.WaitingForActivation` when I run the code through a web request (using IIS Express) that is routed to an ASP.NET MVC controller action.

When I execute the same action method from a unit test, the task completes as expected.

I am using the extension method below to create a Task from the begin/end `CloudBlockBlob.DownloadToStream` methods (from the `WindowsAzure.Storage 2.0.5.1` Nuget package).

```
public static Task DownloadToStreamAsync(
        this CloudBlockBlob blob,
        Stream target)
    {
        if (blob == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("blob");

        var IAsyncResult = blob.BeginDownloadToStream(target, null, null);

        return Task.Factory.FromAsync(IAsyncResult, blob.EndDownloadToStream);
    }
```

Comment: Are you using `Wait()` in your code?

Comment: I am using `await MyTask`. To find out the state of MyTask I added `Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));` just before that `await` statement so that the Task had the time to complete or at least start.